# Set cart shipping total amount issue after Woocommerce update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

After the update my custom shipping amount rules are not working. Before the update I was using the following code to update shipping amount.

```
add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'mysite_box_discount');
function mysite_box_discount($cart ) 
{
  $cart->shipping_total=100;
  return $cart;
}
```

After the update the structure of $cart array has changed and the above code has stopped working. Now the data coming in form of a protected array. I found that $cart->get_shipping_total(); can fetch me shipping amount.

I also found following function to update shipping amount.

```
$cart->set_shipping_total($amount);
```

So I used it in the following way, but its not working.

```
add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'mysite_box_discount');
function mysite_box_discount($cart ) 
{
  $cart->set_shipping_total(100);
  return $cart;
}
```

Can anyone help me and tell how can I use this function or if there is some other way to do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instead `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook to set the cost of your shipping methods, which will be similar to your old code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 10, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ){
    // Loop through shipping methods rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Targeting all shipping methods except "Free shipping"
        if ( 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id ) {
            $has_taxes = false;
            $taxes = [];

            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 100; // Set to 100
            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    $has_taxes = true;
                    $taxes[$key] = 0; // Set to 0 (zero)
                }
            }
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

> **You might need to refresh shipping cached data:** disable, save and enable, save related shipping methods for the current shipping zone, in Woocommerce shipping settings.

In this hook **if you need to loop through cart items** (to make some calculations for example), you will use inside the function code:

```
foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
     $product = $cart_item['data']; // Get the WC_Product instance Object

     // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec, its working now,
i was using the following code to add another element to the cart.
$cart->add_fee( __('Shipping Discount', 'woocommerce'), 10 );
its not working in new version, can you tell me how can i use this, it gives me error:  Call to a member function add_fee() on array.....

Comment: @user974172 Look at this threads containing [woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3730754%20woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees) hook