# Set all shipping methods costs to zero based on cart items subtotal in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

i have multiple shipping methods on my page and want to make them cost zero when the order is above 2500 Czech crowns. I only found the code to only show the Free shipping option when the customer hits the minimum for free shipping but that is not what I want.. I want to show all the methods (but with zero price) so customer still can choose which shipping company he wants his order to be delivered with.
Thank you!

Comment: Note that in StackOverFlow, we expected you to first search, try yourself and provide in your question your own real code attempt. I have answered your question exceptionally as I had to make some small changes to an existing answer code I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Set cart shipping total amount issue after Woocommerce update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538372/set-cart-shipping-total-amount-issue-after-woocommerce-update/53568411#53568411) answer code, here is the way to make it work based on specific cart items subtotal amount:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'null_shipping_costs_conditionally', 10, 2 );
function null_shipping_costs_conditionally( $rates, $package ){
    $threshold_amount = 2500;
    
    if( $package['contents_cost'] >= $threshold_amount ) {
        // Loop through shipping methods rates
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            // Targeting all shipping methods except "Free shipping"
            if ( 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id ) {
                $has_taxes = false;
                $taxes = [];
    
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0; // Set cost to 0 (zero)
                // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
                foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                    if( $tax > 0 ){
                        $has_taxes = true;
                        $taxes[$key] = 0; // Set tax cost to 0 (zero)
                    }
                }
                if( $has_taxes )
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Note:** After saving this code, don't forget to **empty your cart** to refresh shipping cached data.

Comment: thank you so much!! one last thing though, what if I want to add text next to the shipping methods that says "free" ? Now it only deletes the price. Thankss!!

Comment: I accepted the answer, thank you. When I tried to insert the code, it changed both shipping methods to the text that I have entered.. I wanted to put my text next to the shipping methods - eg.  Fedex (Free), not just "Free".

Comment: @TerezaSadílková Is not possible to really answer or understand in this comment Zone… The rule on StackOverFlow is one question at the time.  Please first search, try yourself if you find something or ask a new question.

Comment: What she mean is this; she asked for additional help with adding text after the shipping label and the answer you provided replaces the label all together, making all shipping options called "Here your text" - which is far from optional.