# Add text after shipping method label in woocommerce_package_rates hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, label, shipping-method

I have multiple shipping options on my page and wanted to put the label "free" next to them when the customer buys goods for more then 2500 czech crowns.

I'm using [Set all shipping methods costs to zero based on cart items subtotal in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66137743/11987538) answer code which makes the shipping methods free, but it doesn't put the label next to them, that actually says "free".

I wanted to put my text next to the shipping methods - eg. "Fedex (Free)".

I tried to implement this code:

```php
$rates[$rate_key]->label = __("Here your text", "woocommerce");
```

but it only changes the label of the shipping method, it doesn't put the label next to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `=` but `.=` (concatenating assignment operator)

So just replace

```php
$rates[$rate_key]->label = __("Here your text", "woocommerce");
```

With

```php
$rates[$rate_key]->label .= __( 'Here your text', 'woocommerce' );
```